# NFT Marketplace cards using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, solidity, nft

I am new to blockchain and trying to learn,I have created NFT marketplace application where the functionalities like minting, selling and buying is working fine. But, in the UI after putting it for sale the price of NFT is showing same for all the minted NFTs. I have used {Web3.utils.fromWei(String(price), "ether")}.120000 in the code to display the price of NFT but it is not reflecting the price from blockchain.  [Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy4H3.png)

```html
<CardContent className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.title}>
              <Typography
                className={"MuiTypography--heading"}
                variant={"h5"}
                gutterBottom
              >
                {name}
              </Typography>
              <Chip
                size="small"
                disabled={true}
                label="Selling"
                className={classes.badge}
              />
            </div>
<Typography variant="h6" className={classes.price}>
              <SvgIcon
                component={EthereumLogo}
                viewBox="0 0 400 426.6"
                titleAccess="ETH"
              />
              <span{Web3.utils.fromWei(String(price), "ether")}.120000</span>
  </Typography>
```

Comment: you probably set the same price when you minted nft s

Comment: I have not set any price while minting.  Below is the function for minting @Yilmaz                                                                                           function mint(string memory uri) public returns (uint256){
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    approve(marketplace, newItemId);

    Items[newItemId] = Item({
      id: newItemId, 
      creator: msg.sender,
      uri: uri
    });

    return newItemId;
  }

Comment: If you did not set the price, How do you expect to get the price of nft item?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the price from the listed asset in the Marketplace Contract first. Be aware the NFT Contract and the Marketplace Contract are not the same, these are two different pieces of code. Probably you're getting the price from a constant and not from a Marketplace Contract call.